# Launching Tomcat

Tags: linux, shell, tomcat

I must launch 2 instances of tomcat on a server and with the same user. 
I'm trying to set differents CATALINA_BASE when launching tomcat but this environment variable is not used.

That is the commands I use:

```
base0=/home/$INT/inst0
base1=/home/$INT/inst1
#...

su $INT -c "CATALINA_BASE=$base0;$cathome/bin/startup.sh"
su $INT -c "CATALINA_BASE=$base1;$cathome/bin/startup.sh"
```

and that is what I see in the console:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/mci2/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/mci2/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/mci2/tomcat/temp
```

The catalina_home is ok but not the catalina_base.

Dit I miss something?

Comment: Use CATALINA_HOME instead of CATALINA_BASE.

Comment: The running.txt file says : In CATALINA_BASE:* bin  - Only the following files: * setenv.sh.... 
In CATALINA_HOME: * bin  - Startup and shutdown scripts. My problem is that the CATALINA_BASE variable is not present when the startup.sh script is starting.

Comment: CATALINA_HOME=/home/$INT/inst0  try this

Comment: Perhaps you need to `export CATALINA_BASE=<whatever>` so that `startup.sh` actually inherits that environment variable?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090398/tomcat-catalina-base-and-catalina-home-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use single quotes:

```
su -c "var=Hello; echo $var"
```

vs

```
su -c 'var=Hello; echo $var'
```

The shell interpretes the variables inside the double quotes, and having that you have not set the `CATALINA_BASE` for the env from which you execute `su` it replaces it with and empty string *before* actually executing the `su`.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are running multiple instances of Tomcat on a single host you
>   should set CATALINA_BASE to be equal to the .../tomcat_instance1 or
>   .../tomcat_instance2 directory as appropriate for each instance and
>   the CATALINA_HOME environment variable to the common Tomcat
>   installation whose files will be shared between the two instances.
>   [tomcat - CATALINA_BASE and CATALINA_HOME variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090398/tomcat-catalina-base-and-catalina-home-variables)