# IntelliJIdea: Cannot load /home/.../conf/server.xml:

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I encountered problem with my IDE `Idea 2016.1`

It says:

> Error running run spring: Cannot load
>   /home/sergei-rudenkov/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/system/tomcat//conf/server.xml:
>   /home/sergei-rudenkov/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/system/tomcat//conf/server.xml
>   (No such file or directory)

Actually my `tomcat` situated at `/opt/tomcat` directory and `idea` kmows about it. What can be a reason of this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, be sure you understand the difference between `TOMCAT_HOME` and `TOMCAT_BASE`. This SO answer gives a good description: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29398713/1348743

With that in mind, some explanation of how IDEA creates a `TOMCAT_BASE` directory for Tomcat run configurations... 
When you create a Tomcat Run/Debug configuration, IntelliJ IDEA creates a `TOMCAT_BASE` directory as `{intellij_system_directory}\tomcat\{run_configuration_name}_{project_name}`. (`TOMCAT_HOME` identifies where the binary files are and `TOMCAT_BASE` defines where an instance of tomcat is. Sometimes they are the same. In this case, they are not.) The `{intellij_system_directory}` directory is usually in `~/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/system`. See [Directories used by the IDE to store settings, caches, plugins and logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) for more info).

That's why the path is where it is. But it looks like your path (as you show in the message) is missing the run configuration portion: `.../tomcat//conf/...` That should be something like `.../tomcat/foo_bar/conf/...`. So it seems like a config has gotten corrupt. There is a bug, [IDEA-133536](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-133536), I reported a couple of years ago that can this type of corruption under certain conditions. You may be hitting that.

There are two potential solutions:

1. Recreate your run/debug configurations ensuring you give them a unique name when you first create and save them
2. Manually edit the run/debug configuration file and modify the value for the BASE_DIRECTORY_NAME option (just search for that string). If you have shared the run/debug configuration (via the "share" option in the upper right corner), the configuration file will be in `${project_directory}/.idea/runConfigurations/${runConfigurationName}.xml`. If it is not shared, it will be in the file  `${project_directory}/.idea/workspace.xml`. You should close the project before editing either of those files (and make a backup just in case).

For some additional information, take a look at my post: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206837735--How-To-Specify-Tomcat-Cache-Directory-For-Webapp#community_comment_206857039

Comment: Thanks for answer, sir. There is a directory path, but there is no `server.xml` inside for some reason.

Comment: There is no `server.xml` in `TOMCAT_HOME` either

Comment: reinstallation of `tomcat` solved the problem. Anyway thanks for detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I made `java` point to `JDK` instead of `JRE` - because of a new project, which required `JDK`.
So the old project stopped building and gave the error above.

After returning `java` to point back to `JRE` - the old project builds fine.

=====

So:

1. when working on new project - `java` => `JDK`
2. when working on old project - `java` => `JRE`

:D