# Can glassfish on 8089 port somehow block tomcat on 8088 port?

Tags: java, tomcat

i worked with Tomcat 8.0 without any problem. Then i installed glassfish 4 and set its port on 8089 (works fine), but now i am unable to work with my tomcat server (8088 port).
Weird is that i can start Tomcat without any problem in eclipse (Started state) but in spite of it, i cannot display tomcat site in browser either some projects on tomcat. It throws 404 error.
Where could be a mistake, does anybody please have some idea?
I attached screen of some tomcat settings and how issues looks like.

[image]

Comment: If you are resolving HTTP with both, maybe there's conflict because of the port 80.

Comment: Ports are not your problem since error is HTTP 404. Your app is not correctly deployed on tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using eclipse WTP to manage Tomcat which allows you to choose the following options for server locations:

1. Use workspace metadata (does not modify Tomcat installation)
2. Use tomcat installation (take control of Tomcat installation)

(1) means to create a new tomcat instance to deploy the web app by setting the `$CATALINE_BASE`. This new tomcat instance will not have any default applications. So nothing will be shown if you access the root URL.

(2) means to use the tomcat original instance which is shipped with [a number of default web application](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/security-howto.html#Default_web_applications) (root web , example app , manager app etc.). So if you choose this option , you will see the tomcat welcome page (root web).

Reference :

---

1. [WTP Tomcat FAQ this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ)
2. [CATALINA_HOME vs CATALINE_BASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090398/tomcat-catalina-base-and-catalina-home-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Yes because the tomcat use others ports. Try open glassfish with out tomcat . If work, change default ports of the server into server.XML file and try again with both servers