# How to set up CATALINA_HOME Path correctly?

Tags: java, cmd, path, camunda, catalina

Installed this program and it worked. Next Day I try to open it up and I 
I get the the error

```
The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
```

which is a bit confusing considering the fact that it worked yesterday smoothly

My Path is

```
C:\Java\Camunda\server\apache-tomcat-9.0.19\server\apache-tomcat-9.0.19\bin
```

so I tried to copy it as my CATALINA_HOME path but it didn't work out and since I am a total noob in programming I would appreciate any tipp. Thanks

little side note

my JAVA_HOME path

```
C:\Programme\Java\jre1.8.0_121
```

my JRE_HOME path

```
C:\Programme\Java\jre1.8.0_202
```

How can I set up my CATALNA_HOME Path correctly ?

EDIT:the thread " tomcat - CATALINA_BASE and CATALINA_HOME variables " doesnt solve my problem at all. They highlight the Difference between BASE and HOME. But not my original question: How can i set up my CATALINA_HOME path correctly to run my programm (in this case Camunda)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tomcat - CATALINA\_BASE and CATALINA\_HOME variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090398/tomcat-catalina-base-and-catalina-home-variables)

Comment: I use windows. Additionally i use another Tomcat version

Comment: The question of how to correctly set the CATALINA_HOME Path is not answered in the link you provided. They highlight the difference betwenn HOME and BASE but thats not my question.

Comment: Huh, I thought that "CATALINA_HOME represents the root of your Tomcat installation." was pretty clear.

Comment: I copied the path where I donloaded it but unfortunately it didnt work out my path was C:\Users\ddann\Desktop\mod\server\apache-tomcat-9.0.19 . I am still getting the same error.

Comment: for windows, you need close your console and reopen it after you adjust your environment variable to make them take effect.

Comment: I did but unfortunately the same result

Comment: Should I maybe change the slashes from \ to / ?

Comment: a thing which caught my eye: When I open the cmd it automatically appears C:\Users\ddann but my Catalina Path is not in Users it is in C:\Java\Camunda\... Is this the Problem ?