# Where is myjsp physically published to Tomcat from eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have created a project mytutorial with index.jsp under eclipse 3.3.1 and published it to tomcat by right-clicking. jsp runs but I can't see under Tomcat directory any mytutorial folder so where did it publish my jsp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A technically correct answer is "it depends on your project settings/configuration"

But do check under the following directory -

```
<workspace dir>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\
```

Also, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763693/where-is-the-work-directory-located-for-a-tomcat-instance-running-in-eclipse)